# How can I integrate Robotium test cases with Testlink

Tags: robotium

Is there any way to integrate Robotium test cases with Testlink? 
I can see that we can create and execute Junit test cases in Testlink using Jenkins and Hudson. I am not sure if we can also manage instrumentation test cases on Testlink.

Please someone through light on this?

Comment: I have implemented this solution for webdriver. maybe it will work for robotium as well https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TestLink+Plugin Please note that you should have jenkins installed http://jenkins-ci.org/